# Creating a table filled with values that are derived from a "super"-value

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2, create-table

I'm making a Stored Procedure that receives a @UserId(int) and a @CategoryId(int).
I now have to sever any connection between the user, and the category, however - The user is only directly connected to one or more Subcategories (This connection is found in a table called "HelpWith"), that in turn are connected to a single category each (One category can contain multiple subcategories).
To find the values I have made the following SELECT-statement:

```
SELECT SubcategoryId
FROM [Subcategory] as s
LEFT JOIN [Category] as c ON c.CategoryId = s.CategoryId
WHERE c.Categoryid = @CategoryId
```

The SELECT-statement above can "find" multiple SubcategoryIds and thus, I figured I would have to somehow INSERT the value(s) into a table so that I could do something like:

```
DELETE FROM HelpWith

WHERE SubcategoryId IN (SELECT ID FROM @TempTable)
AND userId = @UserId
```

Does anyone know how this might be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using a JOIN in a DELETE

```
USE [MAPP]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MA_SetTutor_RemoveCategory] 

    @UserId int,
    @CategoryId int

AS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM HelpWith

WHERE SubcategoryId IN
(
    SELECT SubcategoryId
    FROM [Subcategory] AS s
    LEFT JOIN [Category] AS c ON c.CategoryId = s.CategoryId
    WHERE c.CategoryId = @CategoryId
    AND userId = @UserId
)
END
```